# Set iMessage sender in applescript for a new message

Tags: macos, applescript, messages

Applescript allows you to send messages via iMessage and the command line, ie) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812184/how-to-send-an-imessage-text-with-applescript-only-in-provided-service

Is there any way to set the sender of this message to something other than the "start new conversations from" default? I have multiple send/receive addresses and I am able to essentially have conversations with myself and my different verified addresses in iMessage, but only in the native app. Any advice or resources would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Trying to bump this one -- Anyone have an idea here?